# How to achieve this style in using grid or flex?

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

What I'm trying to achieve is like this:

[image]

At first, I was trying to achieve this using `flex` but then I realized it's not possible to make it for the **red box** since flex is one dimensional.

Now I'm trying to figure it out on how to make the **blue box** ***automatically*** fill the remaining space which it seems `flex` is the perfect for that job, and not doable in `grid`.

1. Is it possible to achieve the **blue box** using grid? How?
2. If not, then is it possible to achieve the **red box** with flex? How? (4th tile consume two rows.)

What I'm thinking for now is use `grid` and *leave an empty space* for **red box** and fill it with separate element. But I think that is a dirty trick and the tricky part is the tiles are generated dynamically using a loop. And I'm using `ul li`

```css
#container{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  grid-column-gap:2px;
  grid-row-gap:2px;
  width: 180px;
  list-style:none;
}

.item{
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<ul id="container">
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
</ul>
```

> Edit: Sorry for confusion, maybe it was not clear but what I wanted is the **last tile will fill the remaining space**. I understand that I can, **specifically** use what column it will occupy in `grid` but I what I want is the behavior of `flex-grow` where it will consume the remaining space. Not necessarily the blue tile is in 3-5 column position. The number of tiles is dynamic.

Comment: You want to zoom the red box?

Comment: @ManojKumar more likely, not sure if it's the right term, but I want the 4th tile will have the 2x2 size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we consider the fact that the red element will always be there and you will always have 3 columns then we can easily define all the cases (they are only 3 in total and 1 is by the default)

There is also no restriction *(or maybe few restriction)* on where the red element need to be placed.

```css
.container{
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-gap:2px;
  grid-template-columns:auto auto auto;
  grid-auto-rows:40px;
  grid-auto-columns:40px;
  width:130px;
  grid-auto-flow:dense; /* This one will make the element fill all the empty cells */
}

.item{
  background: grey;
}
.red {
  grid-column:span 2;
  grid-row:span 2;
  background:red;
}

.item:last-child:nth-child(3n+1) {
  grid-column:span 3;
  background:blue;
}
.item:last-child:nth-child(3n+2) {
  grid-column:span 2;
  background:blue;
}
.item:last-child:nth-child(3n+3) {
  background:blue;
}

/* Irrelevant styles */
.container {
  list-style:none;
  margin:5px;
  padding:0;
  border:1px solid green;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<ul class="container">
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item red"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
</ul>

<ul class="container">
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item red"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
</ul>

<ul class="container">
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item red"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
</ul>
<ul class="container">
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item red"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
</ul>
<ul class="container">
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item red"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
</ul>
<ul class="container">
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item red"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
</ul>
<ul class="container">
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item red"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
</ul>

<ul class="container">
  <li class="item red"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
</ul>
<ul class="container">
  <li class="item red"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: wow that is neat. I'm also trying to myself, and I found out using `grid-column-end: -1;` which it seems will do the trick of filling the remaining space in a `grid` layout horizontally but the downside I need to know where the column will start. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your markup is wrong. Need to close `<ul>`. Also, instead of giving dimensions to each `.item` it is better to split the `#container` into cells with the required row and column size and make the `.item` span accordingly.

```css
#container{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 60px);
  grid-template-rows:repeat(4, 60px);
  grid-gap:2px;
  width: 180px;
  list-style:none;
}

.item{
  background: grey;
}

.blue{
  background-color: blue;
  grid-column:2/-1;
  grid-row:4/5;
}
.red{
  background-color: red;
  grid-column:1/3;
  grid-row:2/4;
}
```

```html
<ul id="container">
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item red"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item blue"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I was looking for a solution where the last tile will  ***automatically fill the remaining space*** as mentioned on my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#container{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 60px);
  grid-gap: 2px;
  width: 180px;
  list-style: none;
}

.item{
  background: grey;
}

.blue-box {
  background-color: blue;
  grid-column: 2/-1;
  grid-row: 4;
}

.red-box{
  background-color: red;
  grid-column: 1/3;
  grid-row: 2/4;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="container">
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item red-box"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item blue-box"></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

You can achieve this easily with grid but check if it works on IE/Edge.
On one of my projects grid didn't support on these browsers even after using `-ms- / -moz-`

I am also providing code generated by [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/)

```css
#container{
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: auto 2px auto 2px auto;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  -ms-grid-rows: 60px 2px 60px 2px 60px 2px 60px;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 60px);
  grid-gap: 2px;
  width: 180px;
  list-style: none;
}#container > *:nth-child(1){
  -ms-grid-row: 1;
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
}#container > *:nth-child(2){
  -ms-grid-row: 1;
  -ms-grid-column: 3;
}#container > *:nth-child(3){
  -ms-grid-row: 1;
  -ms-grid-column: 5;
}#container > *:nth-child(4){
  -ms-grid-row: 3;
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
}#container > *:nth-child(5){
  -ms-grid-row: 3;
  -ms-grid-column: 3;
}#container > *:nth-child(6){
  -ms-grid-row: 3;
  -ms-grid-column: 5;
}#container > *:nth-child(7){
  -ms-grid-row: 5;
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
}#container > *:nth-child(8){
  -ms-grid-row: 5;
  -ms-grid-column: 3;
}#container > *:nth-child(9){
  -ms-grid-row: 5;
  -ms-grid-column: 5;
}#container > *:nth-child(10){
  -ms-grid-row: 7;
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
}#container > *:nth-child(11){
  -ms-grid-row: 7;
  -ms-grid-column: 3;
}#container > *:nth-child(12){
  -ms-grid-row: 7;
  -ms-grid-column: 5;
}

.item{
  background: grey;
}

.blue-box {
  background-color: blue;
  grid-column: 2/-1;
  -ms-grid-row: 4;
  grid-row: 4;
}

.red-box{
  background-color: red;
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  -ms-grid-column-span: 2;
  grid-column: 1/3;
  -ms-grid-row: 2;
  -ms-grid-row-span: 2;
  grid-row: 2/4;
}
```

Comment: Same with my comment on Robin, when I tried to delete one `<li>` from your answer the last tile will not occupy the remaining space, which is what I'm expecting for the outcome. Thanks